# loadavg в cgroup

Tags: linux, kernel, docker

Имеется созданный docker контейнер с `--cpuset-cpus="24-31"` (либо просто cpuset cgroup)

```
~# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/6969dd297147e0300e77896cce661e1799f0e738343c687d04bfcc6044a8f213/cpuset.cpus 
24-31
```

Как узнать или вычислить loadavg в пределах данной cgroup (т.е. ограниченно по ядрам, заданным данной cgroup)?

`/proc/loadavg` внутри контейнера показывает информацию по всей системе и всем ядрам